# How to Set a variable inside a Function with Select SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a function that returns a table from employees where they work under a specific employee.

I tried to write the following but I'm getting error:

> An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSubTree (@SupervisorID int)
RETURNS @Result TABLE(
    Id  INT     PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    HIERARCHY   HIERARCHYID    NOT NULL ,
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    LastName   NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    NationalCode    bigint    NOT NULL,
    EmployeeRole    NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hi HIERARCHYID;
    DECLARE @hiT TABLE(
        HI HIERARCHYID
    )
    INSERT into @hiT
    SELECT Top 1 @hi= HIERARCHY
    FROM dbo.Company as C1
    WHERE C1.Id = @SupervisorID;
    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT * 
    FROM   dbo.Company as C
    WHERE   C.HIERARCHY.IsDescendantOf(@hi) = 1 AND C.Id != @SupervisorId;
    RETURN;
End;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Using of implicit column list when inserting is a bad practice. Also suggest you avoiding `*`.

Comment: This ` INSERT into @hiT
    SELECT Top 1 @hi= HIERARCHY` - you are trying to insert data AND assign a variable in the same statement - you can't do that. Given you don't even use `@hiT` - why are you trying to insert records into it? And yes as already stated, list the columns you are inserting into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Split the commands

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSubTree (@SupervisorID int)
RETURNS @Result TABLE(
    Id  INT     PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    HIERARCHY   HIERARCHYID    NOT NULL ,
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    LastName   NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    NationalCode    bigint    NOT NULL,
    EmployeeRole    NVARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hi HIERARCHYID;
    DECLARE @hiT TABLE(
        HI HIERARCHYID
    )

    SELECT Top 1 @hi= HIERARCHY
    FROM dbo.Company as C1
    WHERE C1.Id = @SupervisorID;

    INSERT into @hiT
    VALUES
    (@hi)
    
    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT * 
    FROM   dbo.Company as C
    WHERE   C.HIERARCHY.IsDescendantOf(@hi) = 1 AND C.Id != @SupervisorId;
    RETURN;

End;
```

Comment: I wonder what `@hiT` is even for?

Comment: Be good if you could demonstrate best practice of listing the columns being inserted into.

Comment: This answer solves the problem, best practices are another problem he/she doesn't ask about.

Comment: Any answer on this site should include current best practices as well as solving the problem.

Comment: @Dale-k I guess you are the author of the downvote ;-)

Comment: If I was do you think I would tell you? Nope it wasn't me.

Comment: Another improvement to you answer would be to explain what op was doing wrong.